# JQuery noty buttons click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, noty

I am using Jquery noty to display notification to the user,

> I need to know how can I catch the  confirm buttons click event to
>   preventDefault for each button.

```
noty({
    text: message,
    layout: position, "type": type,
    buttons: [
             {addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Ok', onClick: function ($noty) {    
                            $noty.close();
                        }
              },
              {addClass: 'btn btn-danger', text: 'Cancel', onClick: function ($noty) {
                            $noty.close();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Please Advice,

Comment: post some more sample code, playa -- or can you jsfiddle this dog?

Answer (score 1):

Use preventDefault() like this:

```
{addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Ok', onClick: function (e,$noty) {    
                           e.preventDefault(); 
                           $noty.close();
                        }
              },
```